# Apply EXIF dateCreated data to existing photos

Tags: photos, exif

I'm helping a relative set up a new computer. They've imported all of their photos from the old system to Windows Live Photo Gallery on the new system (running Windows 7), and want the photo's created date to display on the photo (like on their old film-based camera). I've seen tools that can do this one at a time, but this person has over 1000 photos, so I'm looking for a utility that can apply a nice datetime stamp in the corner of the photo in batch mode. I *could* write code for this, but I was hoping for a faster solution.

(I know that the new digital camera can do this automatically and I have configured that, but I still need to fix the existing photos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

> Date/Time Shift Feature
>
> Have you ever forgotten to set the
>   date/time on your digital camera
>   before taking a bunch of pictures?
>   ExifTool has a time shift feature that
>   makes it easy to apply a batch fix to
>   the timestamps of the images (ie.
>   change the "Date Picture Taken"
>   reported by Windows Explorer).
>
> Say for example that your camera clock
>   was reset to `2000:01:01 00:00:00`
>   when you put in a new battery at
>   `2005:11:03 10:48:00`. Then all of the
>   pictures you took subsequently have
>   timestamps that are wrong by 5 years,
>   10 months, 2 days, 10 hours and 48
>   minutes. To fix this, put all of the
>   images in the same directory ("`DIR`")
>   and run exiftool:
>
> `exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal+=5:10:2
>   10:48:0" DIR`
>
> The example above changes only the
>   `DateTimeOriginal` tag, but any
>   writable date or time tag can be
>   shifted, and multiple tags may be
>   written with a single command line.
>   Commonly, in JPEG images, the
>   `DateTimeOriginal`, `CreateDate` and
>   `ModifyDate` values must all be
>   changed. For convenience, a shortcut
>   tag called `AllDates` has been defined
>   to represent these three tags. So, for
>   example, if you forgot to set your
>   camera clock back 1 hour at the end of
>   daylight savings time in the fall, you
>   can fix the images with:
>
> `exiftool -AllDates-=1 DIR`